# Google Cloud Tasks - Maximum number of tasks in a single queue?

Tags: queue, cloud, task, gcloud

Is there a limit set for how many tasks can be created in a single queue? I can't seem to find this info anywhere.

I will probably not execute more than 100 at a time, but I will need to have a lot more waiting in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's none. The only limit mentioned is for the number of Queues that can be added (1000 default, can be increased on your quotas page).
See full details:
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas